# Error con el constructor y los services

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, formularios

```
constructor(private pdpService : PdpService, private tostr : ToastrService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.pdpService.getData();
    this.resetForm();
}
```

Lo que esta dentro del constructor no me muestra el formulario con el que estoy trabajando. Si saco lo que esta dentro, aparece. Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: "Lo que esta dentro del constructor" te refieres a los parametros? Porque el constructor esta vació `{ }`.

Comment: error mio, me estoy refiriendo a los parametros

Comment: No me queda nada claro lo que preguntas, en el constructor simplemente se guardan los Services como atributos de la clase.

Comment: pero cuando guardo los services el formulario con el que estoy trabajando no se muestra

Answer (score 0):

Si estas llamando a un servicio, posiblemente éste te estará devolviendo un observer. Debes guardarlo en una variable, para luego acceder a él.

```
let example: any;
constructor(private pdpService : PdpService, private tostr : ToastrService) { }

ngOnInit() {
            this.pdpService.getData().subscribe(data => this.example = data);
            this.resetForm();
        }
```